Как добавить классу возможность получать значения в виде "my_class[2]"?
Вот таким образом:
arr = SparseArray()
arr[1] = 10
arr[8] = 20


Для присваивания нужно переопределить метод __setitem__, для получения значения __getitem__. Для полноты реализации еще __len__ нужен и __delitem__. Посмотрите тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/186608/#sequence

В классах можно определять метод __getitem__, который возвращает какое-либо значение, когда мы обращаемся к нему по индексу:
class SparseArray:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # если значение или тип ключа некорректны, list выбросит исключение
        return self.values[key]

Почитайте про магические методы, там много всего полезного
